# Buttons and Events in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How come when you do button1.Enabled = false; if you still click it the Event Handler Click that was added to earlier will still trigger it ?

I want to disable the button so when pressing it won't trigger the .Click event without doing button1.Click -= new EventHandler(panel_Click);

What should i do?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET, WPF, or WinForms?

Comment: is this winforms or webforms?

Comment: I think the `click` event will never be triggered if its button is disabled, for most UI controls from most languages on most platforms.

Comment: @Jeff M, yes, that was my mistake. because I during my coding I changed the PictureBox array to Button Array and the click event wasn't updated, thx... all works now

Comment: Ah nuts, I was slow writing out my example.  But looks like the problem is resolved now.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tested if the event will still trigger. Seems counterintuitive that it would. You could simply overcome this by placing the following statement in your callback method

```
if (!button1.Enabled)
{
   return;
}
```

This will break out of your method so any subsequent code will not execute.

Edit:

After performing tests in both ASP.Net and Win Forms, it must simply be that you have a rogue line of code calling this method. Easy mistake to make, and very hard sometimes to track down. However, utlizing the Call Stack Window makes this cake.

Simply place a break point in your callback method. When it's reached click on the menu Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack

This will show you where the method was invoked from. Double click on any given item in the window and it will redirect you to the method where the invocation occurs. You will find your bug using this.

Comment: If this is ASP.NET then this will not be a good approach because you will waste time performing an unnecessary Post Back

Comment: @Matthew Cox, its not Asp, its Windows Form application

Comment: Additional note, I just did a sample test with ASP.Net. Callbacks are not initiated on buttons in the form that have Enabled = "false"

Comment: @Alon B  The code sample will work just fine for Win Forms as well. However, it still means technically wasting time on a unnecessary callback. Let me fire up a win forms app and see what I can reproduce

Comment: @Matthew Cox, Seems like if that button1 has a click assigned to it, then even if do button1.enable = false, if i click the button it will still trigger it. is there away to overcome it without removing the click event handler?

Comment: @Alon B I just created a simple app that has a button that is disabled. I placed a break point in the callback method. It is never reached. This indicates that you must have a bug that is circumventing and reaching the method. Perhaps you have a rogue line somewhere that is also calling the method. Good Way to find out: Place a break point inside your callback method, then when its reached, open the CallStack Window in Visual Studios, it will show you the calls that lead to invoking the method

Comment: @Matthew Cox, I found the problem. You were right. I had this.panelBoardGame.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_Click); which means that not only when I pressed the button, but also when I pressed the panel it triggered that function. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Paste your some part of code if possible. To do this ,right click on the button, Select Find All References and paste all the code where the button is referenced. This will help us in finding the actual thing.Normally a button click event does not get fired if the control is set disabled.

Comment: @Alon B I'm glad it helped. The Call Stack window is awesome for this type of scenario and especially helpful when learning your way around someone else's code.

Comment: @AmRan, I coded the Buttons array without Draging it with the toolbox, so I have no button to right click on :)

Comment: @Matthew Cox, I don't know how to use the callstack windows, so I found my problem in the GameForm.Designer.cs file :)

Comment: @Alon B haha well I suggest you use it. It will make it so much easier in the future. It's very easy to use. Look up a tutorial if you didn't feel like my explanation was inadequate. They usually have screen dumps for visuals as well.

Comment: @AlonB - ok no issues , hoping your issue is fixed now. -)

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't trigger the `Click` Event.

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var button = new Button {Enabled = false};

    button.Click += ButtonClick;

    Controls.Add(button);
}

void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(@"Clicked!");
}
```

The above will add a button that is disabled to your form, and the MessageBox will not show. But if you set Enabled to true, it will.

Comment: +1 - I just finished writing a similar example but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: Ya I wrote one too. If you see comment I posted below. =D This really just indicates that he has a bug in his application. Probably a rogue line of code. I suggest that he should use the Call Stack Window in Visual Studios to trace where his method is being invoked from ... I am willing to bet it's not coming from his button if it is truly disabled.

Comment: @Matthew - Yes, I remember making similar mistakes as a novice.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are attempting to remove the `panel_Click` handler from the *button's* click event.  Are you sure the click event for the button is being fired?  Does the panel that the button is added to have a click handler?  Even if the button is disabled, any other controls behind it that have applicable events will still fire.

Here's a small demonstration:

```
public class TestForm : Form
{
    public TestForm()
    {
        this.Text = "Test Form";

        var panel = new FlowLayoutPanel
        {
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
        };
        var button = new Button
        {
            Text = "Button!",
            Enabled = false,
        };
        var cb = new CheckBox
        {
            Text = "Buton Enabled",
            Checked = false,
        };

        panel.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("Panel clicked!");
        button.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("Button clicked!");
        this.Click += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("Form clicked!");
        cb.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) => button.Enabled = cb.Checked;

        panel.Controls.Add(button);
        panel.Controls.Add(cb);
        this.Controls.Add(panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: M, I had a mistake in my code. when you disable the button, it shouldnt trigger the button click, but in my code something else triggered it. so now its all fixed. thx for your help :)

Comment: @Alon: Ah so you added the button's click handler to the panel's click event right?  That would be a different situation then.  ;)